# Allow only letters; no punctuation no numbers

Tags: php, regex

Hey guys can you help me with this. I've got this '/[^A-Za-z]/' but cannot figure out the punctuations part.

Gracious!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The regular expression you are using doesn't allow letters; it's the opposite of what you are reported in the title.

`/[a-z]/i` is enough, if you want to accept only letters. If you want to allow letters like à, è, or ç, then you should expand the regular expression; `/[\p{L}]/ui` should work with all the Unicode letters.

Answer (score 2):

```
#^[^a-z]+$#i
```

Your code was correct, you just need ^ and $. So it means **all** character from the beginning to the end doesn't allow outside alphabet. Negative match is preferred than positive match here.

Comment: it means like this: <code>if (preg_match('#^[^a-z]+$#i', $string) echo 'outside alphabet found';</code>

Answer (score 1):

/[^A-Za-z]*/ will match everything except letters. You shouldn't need to specify numbers or punctuation.

Comment: While what you said is true, it doesn't answer the question. See kiamlaluno's answer.

Comment: Actually for what I'm doing kurrel is right. but this is a mistake in how I asked the question and in my own code execution. - 2 for me, my apologies. My original regex actually works as needed.

Comment: kiamlaluno's second version is more flexible with respect to extra characters for sure, but if you're using the regex in say an if-statement to match what you don't want, you're going to be looking for negatives instead of positives.

Answer (score 0):

Inside of a character class, the ^ means not.
So you're looking for **not** a letter.
You want something like

```
[A-Za-z]+
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also use the shorthand `\w` for a "word character" (alphanumeric plus _).  Of course some regex engines may differ on support for this, but if it's PCRE it should work.  [See here](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html) (under heading "escape sequences").